# Завершить Intent Service - Android

Tags: java, android, service, android-intent

Друзья подскажите пожалуйста, задача такая работает `IntentService` когда выполняет задачу он запускает другой сервис из которого мне нужно убить старый сервис - как это сделать? использую это:

```
stopService(new Intent(service_scan.this, gate_service.class));
```

Comment: И он типа не завершается?...

Comment: Нет работает как будто не чего и не происходило иза этого висит Activity который и запускает данный сервис.

Comment: А как вы поняли, что сервис не помирает? Вы выводите в логи в методе смерти сервиса что-то, но этот метод не вызывается? Может просто вы потом запускаете обычный сервис которы и тормозит активити, а ИнтентСервис благополучно умер? Мало инфы.

Comment: У меня логи идут:

D/STATUS: gate_sevice
D/STATUS: Activity dialog
D/STATUS: gate_sevice
D/STATUS: gate_sevice loop
D/STATUS: loop time set to 24
D/STATUS: gate_sevice
 D/STATUS: gate_sevice
D/STATUS: service_scan
D/STATUS: gate_sevice loop
D/STATUS: loop time set to 19
D/STATUS: gate_sevice
D/STATUS: gate_sevice

Comment: После Activity dialog не должно не чего идти а оно идет

Comment: Добавьте это в вопрос с пояснениями.

Comment: И туда же добавьте код запуска сервисов

Answer (score 3):

IntentService должен останавливаться сам если нет задач:

> IntentService is a base class for Services that handle asynchronous requests (expressed as Intents) on demand. Clients send requests through startService(Intent) calls; the service is started as needed, handles each Intent in turn using a worker thread, and stops itself when it runs out of work.

Не очень понятна связь между активити и сервисом, каким образом они связаны. Как вариант используйте BoundService - как только сделаете unbind то система его остановит.

> unbindService (ServiceConnection conn)
>
> Added in API level 1 Disconnect from an application service. You will
>   no longer receive calls as the service is restarted, and the service
>   is now allowed to stop at any time.